# A Java based modifyable web shop platform?

Tags: cms, ecommerce, java

I have a project which requires a web shop. It should be a Java based web shop, since I know Java well.

The functional requirements are:

- modifiable layout for main/goods pages
- modifiable processes like checking out etc.

Is there a solution, which would meet my requirenments, which I should prefer? (e.g. something as popular as Magento)

Comment: You can find [what you want on Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cms+e-commerce+java).

Comment: Tnx! Seems that my question was not precise enought, what I am looking for is not for any solution, but for a PREFERABLE solution.
Maybe someone has already gained some expirience with such a system and can provide some explanation?